# jQuery: how do I loop through all 'a' elements?

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to change all the anchor's properties on a page.  But I don't know how to loop through all of them.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

use each:

http://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$("a").each(function(){
    //do something with the element here.
});
```

Comment: "the element" that akellehe mentions is referenced via the `this` keyword inside the function.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) with a function to change a specific property, for example:

```
$("a").attr("href", function(i, oldHref) {
  return oldHref + "#hash";
});
```

This is cheaper than [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) since you're not creating an extra jQuery object inside each iteration, you're accessing the properties on the DOM element without doing that.

Answer (score 6):

jQuery provides this ability inherently.

```
$('a').do_something();
```

Will `do_something()` to every `a` on the page. So:

```
$('a').addClass('fresh'); // adds "fresh" class to every link.
```

If what you want to do requires looking at the properties of each `a` individually, then use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$('a').each( function(){
  var hasfoo = $(this).hasClass('foo'); // does it have foo class?
  var newclass = hasfoo ? 'bar' : 'baz'; 
  $(this).addClass(newclass); // conditionally add another class
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('a').each(function(i){
    $(this).attr('href','xyz');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) for this purpose:

```
$('a').each(function() {   
 // The $(this) jQuery object wraps an instance  
 // of an anchor element.  
});
```