# Selecting every nth of the same type of element, but not within the same parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

How can I go about grabbing every element of a certain type (a) on page, regardless of whether they're in the parent container or not, and add a certain class to every nth iteration?

I'm trying to cycle all of my links through 5 different colors in order. So every 5n+0 link is blue, every 5n+1 is red, & so on. The problem stopping me from using css nth-childs is that they're mostly contained within different paragraphs and are all considered under 5n+0.

I (think) I know to start off with `document.querySelectorAll("a")`, but not what to do from there....

Comment: Possible duplicate.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610621/jquery-how-do-i-loop-through-all-a-elements - if you are using jQuery you would do: $("a").each(function() { /* code that does stuff */ });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate with `.each()` and then add color/Class accordingly to index(*nth element*)

```
$('a').each(function(index, element){
  switch(index%5){
    case 0:
        $(element).addClass('blueColor');
        break;
    case 1:
        $(element).addClass('redColor');
        break;
    default:
    //Whatever    
  }
});
```

[Fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/pLrdu94q/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Collect all links into an array:

> ```
> let linx = Array.from(document.links);
> ```

Run through a `for` loop and assign a color from a color array, see demo

---

### Demo

```js
let colors = ['cyan', 'lime', 'tomato', 'gold', 'violet'];

let linx = Array.from(document.links);

let count = 0;

for (let c = 0; c < linx.length; c++) {
  count++;
  if (count === 5) {
    count = 0;
  } 
  linx[c].style.color = colors[count];
}
```

```html
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
<a href='#/'>LINK</a>
```

Comment: This is cool, thanks! The only reason I chose the other answer as the accepted one is because it works a bit more out of the box for my particular case (I need to limit the array to a single container to avoid the nav, with `$('.container a')`